# Test-ServiceFabricApplicationPackage Settings.xml already exists

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I am using sdk 3.3.622.9590 and having some difficulty deploying my application using powershell.

The error is like follows:
**Test-ServiceFabricApplicationPackage : The file 'C:\Users\xxx\A
ppData\Local\Temp\TestApplicationPackage_740405352\n2r3lbmn.zlv\Release(service name)\Config\Settings.xml' already exists.**
At C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Service Fabric\Tools\PSModule\ServiceFabricS
DK\Publish-NewServiceFabricApplication.ps1:163 char:38
+ ... tionSuccess = (Test-ServiceFabricApplicationPackage $AppPkgPathToUse)

My application structure is like this

Applicaiton Folder

- Service 1

  - Code
  - Config

    - Settings.xml
  - ServiceManifest.xml
- Service 2...

I managed to deploy twice, but the other times it all failed with the same error.

I am new to SF and powershell. Can someone please help me and point me to the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please share the link to the doc you have been following to achieve this so that I can try to reproduce your issue. Thanks.
Refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-deploy-remove-applications

Comment: Have you tried to run `Test-ServiceFabricApplicationPackage` manually on application package being created? (the package is placed in the **Service Fabric Application project\pkg** directory during the build by default).

Comment: The Test-ServiceFabricApplicationPackage cmdlet is begin run as part of the deployment, it uses a temp directory in the test (copying the package there, seems like somehow this fails). Could you try to empty the temp folder and rerun just the cmdlet?

Comment: where is this folder ?  Could you try to empty the temp folder and rerun just the cmdlet?

Comment: I have also asked here no response coming up. https://github.com/Azure/service-fabric-issues/issues/1414 Also when we rebooted the servers at the same time..it created a disaster for us.

Comment: Could it be a permissions problem? It may be having problems trying to overwrite a file created on a previous deployment. Starting powershell with Administrator privileges may help if that is the problem.

Comment: Find your application package, get it onto your machine and get into the root package directory, then call "Tree" - Do you see two Settings.xml files next to each other within a given config package? Can you share the output? If you capture the app package, try also Test-ServiceFabricApplicationPackage -Verbose

Answer (score 0):

Just in case it may help anyone who hits this, we were using a self-hosted agent to run the pipeline. Switching the fabric publish task to use an Azure hosted agent seems not to exhibit the same problem.

Hope this helps

Mark

Answer (score 0):

As a short term workaround - until Microsoft fix the issue formally, I've managed to mitigate the problem...

What was needed was to ensure that the workspace was cleaned before each and every action involving the application.  Build and each release stage.

My specific instance was when using the multi-stage YAML file for build and deployment so adding in a workspace: clean was what was needed.

I still have a support ticket with Microsoft for a more formal fix.